# Como fazer um valor retornado de um método ser exibido na tela em C#?

Tags: c#

Queria saber como eu exibo um valor na tela que foi retornado de um método, já pesquisei muito e não achei nada que resolvesse minha dúvida, não compreendi a maioria dos sites que visitei para ver sobre como fazia isso. Sempre que tento exibir o tal valor na tela, ele simplesmente não aparece. Ainda sou um iniciante em C# e certas coisas ainda estão sendo difíceis pra mim. (Estou usando o Visual Studio 2022)

```
using System;

namespace MétodosPrática2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int Resultado, N1, N2;
        static void Main()
        {
            N1 = 10;
            N2 = 10;
            Resultado = calculo(Resultado, N1, N2);
            Console.WriteLine(Resultado);
        }
        
        static public int calculo (int resultado, int n1, int n2)
        {
            resultado = n1 + n2;
            return resultado;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: rodei aqui, tá certo cara. btw, no stackoverflow, posta o código em vez da imagem.

Comment: O ideal seria não passar `resultado` como parâmetro no método `calculo`, pois não faz sentido, sugiro remover o parâmetro resultado da função `calculo` e deixar o `return` da soma direto, ex:  `return n1 + n2;`.

Comment: Já fiz as devidas alterações no post, agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme já mencionado antes não tem a necessidade de utilizar a variável `resultado` como parâmetro no método. Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação sobre métodos [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods).

Para que se possa exibir o valor na tela, você pode fazer a correção do código e deixar mais ou menos desse jeito:

```
using System;

namespace MetodosPratica2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int Resultado, N1, N2;
        static void Main()
        {
            N1 = 10;
            N2 = 10;
            Resultado = calculo(N1, N2);
            Console.WriteLine(Resultado);
        }

        static public int calculo(int n1, int n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;;
        }

    }
}
```

Caso haja realmente a necessidade de utilizar um parâmetro do método para que seja retornado um valor, será necessário realizar algumas alterações e utilizar um modificador de parâmetro, onde você pode ver a documentação [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). Neste caso não será necessário usar um retorno no método, sendo assim o seu código deverá ficar com a seguinte estrutura:

```
using System;

namespace MetodosPratica2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int Resultado, N1, N2;
        static void Main()
        {
            N1 = 10;
            N2 = 10;
            calculo(out Resultado, N1, N2);
            Console.WriteLine(Resultado);
        }

        static public void calculo(out int resultado, int n1, int n2)
        {
            resultado = n1 + n2;
        }
    }
}
```

A utilização do segundo caso eu vejo como um ponto bem específico dentro de um sistema, é mais comum utilizarmos a primeira opção.

Comment: Outro ponto que eu acrescentaria é apenas utilizar variáveis globais quando realmente existe a necessidade.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

namespace MétodosPrática2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int Resultado, N1, N2;
        static void Main()
        {
            N1 = 10;
            N2 = 10;
            Resultado = calculo(N1, N2);
            Console.WriteLine(Resultado);
        }

        static public int calculo(int n1, int n2)
        {
            int resultado = n1 + n2;
            return resultado;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).